# Ethereum node vs Ethereum accounts

Tags: contract-development, accounts

From my understanding, one Ethereum node can have many accounts and only one of the account can perform mining in each node. So, my question will be what are the usage of other accounts in the node then? If an account deployed a contract, can other accounts call function of that contract even they are from the same node?

*Please correct me if my understanding are wrong. Thanks.

Comment: Mining node requires one account to act as coinbase account, and whenever a block is found, the block reward will go to already set coinbase account.

Comment: Then what is the usage of other accounts in a particular node?

Comment: You can have balances in multiple accounts... you can deploy different contracts With different accounts...

Answer (score 1):

"can other accounts call function of that contract even they are from the same node?" => Yes they can.

Other accounts can have each balances.

Node can accept RPC(remote procedure call) request, and through RPC request, each node's accounts can send transaction and create smart contract.

Multiple node's accounts are useful to simulate some transactions when developing.

Answer (score 1):

An ethereum node is a computer running ethereum server software. It exposes RPC API  defined by ethereum protocol: https://ethereum.github.io/execution-apis/api-documentation
Node solves (before 2022 fork, using Proof of Work algo) a heavy computational problem to "prove a block". There is only one miner (node) who confirms a block and gets rewards for it. A block contains many transactions between different addresses.
To get a better understanding of ethereum structure read https://github.com/ethereumbook/ethereumbook
This book however will become outdated partially as ethereum moves to proof of stake this year (2022).